# Provide access to external users sharepoint online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

My company has different entities(14).One of entity has the 
Sharepoint online we have developed one website.Need to provide access to all employees(20k)(all employees are not accessible by this sharepoint and does not have the outlook account).There is no central active directory.
Please suggest how to provide access.